# How to grant the same privilege for multiple tables to a user in Maria DB?

Tags: mariadb, permissions

I have a database on MariaDB with multiple tables and I want to give the same privileges for diferents tables to the same user. I have the next tables:

```
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_sales     |
+---------------------+
| customer            |
| product             |
| sale                |
| employee            |
| supplier            |
+---------------------+
```

And for example, I have tried with the next command.

```
GRANT SELECT on customer, product, sale to 'seller'@'localhost';
```

Is there any chance to do that or I have to give the same privilege to each of the tables?

Comment: When you need to provide some definite privileges set to all database tables then simply provide these privileges to `database.*` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is constrained by the [grant syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/). So multiple `grants` are needed:

```
GRANT SELECT on sales.customer to 'seller'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT on sales.product to 'seller'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT on sales.sale to 'seller'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT on sales.employee to 'seller'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT on sales.supplier to 'seller'@'localhost';
```